# Way to parse jsbin output html document for content within 'javascript' field

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, dom

I have a jsbin here https://jsbin.com/wanegavisa/edit?html,js,console and I'm trying to use nodejs to download the output html https://output.jsbin.com/wanegavisa and parse out the content within the `javascript` tab in the jsbin editor. I was going to use a dom parser like cheerio and get the first `<script>` tag within the `body`. I just saw that one can add script tags directly to the body.

How can I parse a document like this can get a string containing

```
console.log('hi')
```

I could select the script sibling from the script with src that's equal to this url `https://static.jsbin.com/js/render/edit.js`. But if that url changes then I'm out of luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<!--
Created using JS Bin
http://jsbin.com

Copyright (c) 2016 by anonymous (http://jsbin.com/wanegavisa/2/edit)

Released under the MIT license: http://jsbin.mit-license.org
-->
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script>console.log('meow')</script>

<script>
console.log('hi')
</script>
<script src="https://static.jsbin.com/js/render/edit.js?3.35.12"></script>
<script>jsbinShowEdit && jsbinShowEdit({"static":"https://static.jsbin.com","root":"https://jsbin.com"});</script>
<script src="https://static.jsbin.com/js/vendor/eventsource.js?3.35.12"></script>
<script src="https://static.jsbin.com/js/spike.js?3.35.12"></script>
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-1656750-34', 'jsbin.com');
ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use the api instead https://jsbin.com/api/wanegavisa

Answer (score 0):

jsbin has an api! :)

https://jsbin.com/api/wanegavisa

```
{
  "javascript": "console.log('hi')",
  "html": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<script src=\"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js\"></script>\n  <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n  <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width\">\n  <title>JS Bin</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n\n  <script>console.log('meow')</script>\n  \n</body>\n</html>",
  "css": "",
  "settings": {
    "processors": {
      "html": "html",
      "css": "css",
      "javascript": "javascript"
    },
    "title": "JS Bin"
  },
  "last_updated": "2012-07-23T00:00:00.000Z",
  "url": "wanegavisa",
  "snapshot": 2
}
```